# Emoji like Application

Tags: iphone

I want to create Custom Keyboard application like Emoji app.
I know how to enable emoji in the iphone but my question is from were the icons are coming
and how i can add my own icons to emoji keyboard or i have to make my own keyboard separate.

This all should work with all app like email, notes etc...

Please advice some solution.

Answer (score 0):

too late but it might helps to another [Custom Emoji Board Example](http://blog.jorgedelprado.com.ar/selector-personalizado-de-emoji/)

Comment: The link seems to be broken now